# System.ObjectDisposedException on Form Closing

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge, formclosing

I have a C# WinForms app that uses AForge for video playback from a file stream(fs), which is created using a byte array (TheVideoInBytes). After the video is created in the filestream, it starts playback (private void tsbtnPlayPause_Click) using "private void video_NewFrame".

Here's the code for playback:

```
    private void tsbtnPlayPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tsbtnPlayStop.Text == "▶")
        {
            try
            {
                TheVideoInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(glbstrVideo);
                System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("whatever", System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                fs.Write(TheVideoInBytes, 0, TheVideoInBytes.Length);
                videoSource.Source = "whatever";

                videoSource.Start();
                videoSource.PlayingFinished += VideoSource_PlayingFinished;
                tsbtnPlayStop.Text = "█";
                fs.Dispose();
                fs.Close();

                //videoSource.Source = ofd.FileName;
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                tsbtnCloseMedia.Enabled = tsbtnPlayStop.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "oops.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            tsbtnPlayStop.Text = "▶";
            videoSource.Source = null;
            System.IO.File.Delete("whatever");
        }
    }
```

...and here's the code for the frames:

```
    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                pbVid.Image = bitmap;
                pbVid.Refresh();
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "oops.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Problem: If I close the main form (frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)) while playback is in progress, the app crashes with the following message:

System.IO.IOException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024864
  Message=The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

System.ObjectDisposedException Cannot access a disposed object.

This error occurs at this line in private void video_NewFrame:

```
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
```

How can I kill this process safely and exactly where should the code be written?

Comment: what does the code in the close look like then..? perhaps you need to dispose of the object prior to closing the form..

Comment: Since you have an Invoke there, I presume the video_NewFrame callback is happening on a different thread.  It is possible that this background thread is doing something when the close form occurs (It is likely waiting at the Invoke to be able to get into the main thread.  In general, subscribed callbacks need to tolerate having their source go away before they are invoked.   You need to put some guards inside that invoke delegate to do an early return if this happens.

Comment: You have to delay closing the window until the video player stopped.  Use the FormClosing event, call SignalToStop(), set e.Cancel = true and set a bool variable to true to indicate that you are busy closing the window.  When you get the PlayingFinished event then check that bool and now you can safely close the window.